# Error! coreML model prediction on image is wrong , on video is correct

Tags: ios, swift, machine-learning, computer-vision, coreml

I am using CoreML in an example iOS app with my custom trained object detection model. The model when used on video frames is able to perform well and shows the correct class detections and bounding boxes.

When used on an image, the **bounding box detections are all wrong and all predictions are classified to 1 class.**

the model setup in the two cases is the same.

**the model prediction call is handled as**

```
func processClassifications(for request: VNRequest, error: Error?) -> [Prediction]? {

    let results = request.results

    let results1 = results as! [VNCoreMLFeatureValueObservation]

    let results2 = try? postprocess().prediction( output: results1[0].featureValue.multiArrayValue! )

    // Some processing from results2 -> predictions

    return predictions
}
```

**For the video:**

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {
    let pixelBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)

    // self.visionModel is same as the "  MODEL_TF2keras_OutConv12().model " below...

    guard let visionModel = self.visionModel

    var requestOptions:[VNImageOption : Any] = [:]
    if let cameraIntrinsicData = CMGetAttachment(sampleBuffer, kCMSampleBufferAttachmentKey_CameraIntrinsicMatrix, nil) {
        requestOptions = [.cameraIntrinsics:cameraIntrinsicData]
    }
    let orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation(rawValue: UInt32(EXIFOrientation.rightTop.rawValue))

    let trackingRequest = VNCoreMLRequest(model: visionModel) { (request, error) in
    guard let predictions = self.processClassifications(for: request, error: error) else { return }. // This function performs the coreML model on the frame and return the predictions.
    }
    trackingRequest.imageCropAndScaleOption = VNImageCropAndScaleOption.centerCrop

    let imageRequestHandler = VNImageRequestHandler(cvPixelBuffer: pixelBuffer, orientation: orientation!, options: requestOptions)
    try imageRequestHandler.perform([trackingRequest])

    }
}
```

**Where as for the Single image the prediction is handled as:**

```
lazy var classificationRequest: VNCoreMLRequest = {

        let model = try VNCoreMLModel(for: MODEL_TF2keras_OutConv12().model)

        let request = VNCoreMLRequest(model: model, completionHandler: { [weak self] request, error in
            let predictions =  self?.processClassifications(for: request, error: error)
        })
        request.imageCropAndScaleOption = VNImageCropAndScaleOption.centerCrop
        return request
    }
}()

func updateClassifications(for image: UIImage) {

    let orientation = CGImagePropertyOrientation(image.imageOrientation)
    guard let ciImage = CIImage(image: image)

    let handler = VNImageRequestHandler(ciImage: ciImage, orientation: orientation)
    handler.perform([self.classificationRequest])
    }
```

In my understanding the issue lies in using CVPixelbuffer in the video case and a CIImage in the single image case.

The question is: **why is such a difference happening when the function and model call is the same.**

How can I solve this problem ?

Appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

The key errors included

- the orientation of the images were getting mixed in conversion. The video sequence retained the orientation.
- The model output was corrupted during conversion. A re-conversion from the first step resolved the issue. Thus, my own mistake, however an important observation. Due to so many steps in conversion from one platform to another, the possible sources of error are manyfold and it helped to start from the first step.
- the image resizing and app ImageView resizing was affecting the visualization of the bounding boxes. Thus it is important to check these. I made the naive inference that the predictions were incorrect, whereas, the visualization was incorrect.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this! We are working on a similar issue. Any chance you can provide us with a paid consultant?